# How do i generate qr code from url in javascript

Tags: javascript

so i building a url shortner  which takes the url from python and generates a QR code in along with the shortUrl, i am using jinja2template for the UI, as i am very new to JavaScript the below code is mostly copied from Youtube and Internet.

This is the class which will show the converted shortUrl and will have a copy link button next o it

```
            <div class = "result__container">
                <div class = "shorturl">
                    <div id="qrcode"></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onclick = "copyLink()">Copy Link</button>

                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the logic create the qr code I am using qrcode.min.js here to create the qrcode

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/qrcode.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        const qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById('qrcode'), {
            text: response.shortUrl,
            width: 128,
            height: 128,
            colorDark : '#000',
            colorLight : '#fff',
            correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
    });
```

```
            xhr.onload = function () {
                const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                console.log(this.status);
                console.log(response);
                if(this.status ==200){
                    resultContainer.style.display = "flex";
                    shortUrl.innerHTML = `SHORT URL :- <a href=${response.shortUrl}>${response.shortUrl}</a>`
                }
                else{
                    alert(`An error occurred, ${response.detail}`)
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This simple library by David Shim makes it easy!

```js
const qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById('qrcode'), {
  text: 'http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie',
  width: 128,
  height: 128,
  colorDark : '#000',
  colorLight : '#fff',
  correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/qrcode.min.js"></script>

<div id="qrcode"></div>
```

You can also get really fancy with your styling and actions. here is an example I built using the same foundational code. After styling the QR code and document, I added three action buttons on hover which will download, copy, or visit the QR/source accordingly. Unfortunately, these buttons do not work in iframes due to permission issues, so they will not function in the StackOverflow snippet, or on CodePen, JSFiddle, CodeSandbox, etc. However, you can load this code into your own server to see it all work perfectly.

Here is the finished product:

```js
const qrElement = document.getElementById('qrcode');

const qrUrl = 'https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/';

const qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById('qrcode'), {
  text: qrUrl,
  width: 128,
  height: 128,
  colorDark : '#000',
  colorLight : '#fff',
  correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});

const qrActionButtons = Array.from(qrElement.querySelectorAll('.qr-action'));

qrActionButtons.find(b => b.dataset.qrAction === 'visit').href = qrUrl;

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target) {
    if (qrActionButtons.indexOf(e.target) !== -1) {
      const button = e.target;
      const action = button.dataset.qrAction;
      if (action === 'download') {
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = 'QR-Code.png';
        a.href = qrElement.querySelector('img').src;
        console.log(a.href);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
      } else if (action === 'copy') {
        fetch(qrElement.querySelector('img').src).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({[blob.type]:blob})]));
      } else if (action === 'visit') {
        // handled organically
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --theme-color: #ff0;
  --trace-size: 6%;
  --trace-distance: 5%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  background-color: var(--theme-color);
}
#qrcode {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}
#qrcode {
  background-color: inherit;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}
#qrcode::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: var(--trace-size);
  height: var(--trace-size);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 20%;
  animation: 2s ease-in-out 1s infinite normal both qr-trace;
  transition: inherit;
}
#qrcode img {
  background-color: inherit;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  transition: inherit;
}
#qrcode .qr-action {
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 33%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#qrcode .qr-action::before,
#qrcode .qr-action::after {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  font-weight: 900;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -10px #000;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all .45s ease-out;
}
#qrcode .qr-action::before {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
#qrcode .qr-action::after {
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(0.95);
  background-color: #000;
  color: var(--theme-color);
}
#qrcode .qr-action[data-qr-action="download"]::before,
#qrcode .qr-action[data-qr-action="download"]::after {
  content: '\f381';
}
#qrcode .qr-action[data-qr-action="copy"]::before,
#qrcode .qr-action[data-qr-action="copy"]::after {
  content: '\f0c5';
}
#qrcode .qr-action[data-qr-action="visit"]::before,
#qrcode .qr-action[data-qr-action="visit"]::after {
  content: '\f0c1';
}
#qrcode .qr-action:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(-175%, -50%) scale(0);
}
#qrcode .qr-action:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}
#qrcode .qr-action:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(75%, -50%) scale(0);
}
#qrcode .qr-action i,
#qrcode .qr-action svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}
#qrcode:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}
#qrcode:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#qrcode:hover .qr-action {
  opacity: 1;
}
#qrcode:hover .qr-action:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(-175%, -50%) scale(1);
}
#qrcode:hover .qr-action:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
#qrcode:hover .qr-action:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(75%, -50%) scale(1);
}
#qrcode:hover .qr-action:hover::before {
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(0.95) rotateY(180deg);
}
#qrcode:hover .qr-action:hover::after {
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1) rotateY(180deg);
}
@keyframes qr-trace {
  0%, 10% {
    left: calc(-1 * (var(--trace-size) + var(--trace-distance)));
    top: calc(-1 * (var(--trace-size) + var(--trace-distance)));
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  } 25%, 35% {
    left: calc(100% + var(--trace-distance));
    top: calc(-1 * (var(--trace-size) + var(--trace-distance)));
  } 50%, 60% {
    left: calc(100% + var(--trace-distance));
    top: calc(100% + var(--trace-distance));
  } 75%, 85% {
    left: calc(-1 * (var(--trace-size) + var(--trace-distance)));
    top: calc(100% + var(--trace-distance));
  } 100% {
    left: calc(-1 * (var(--trace-size) + var(--trace-distance)));
    top: calc(-1 * (var(--trace-size) + var(--trace-distance)));
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/qrcode.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/07afc061fe.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="qrcode"><button class="qr-action" data-qr-action="download"></button><button class="qr-action" data-qr-action="copy"></button><a class="qr-action" data-qr-action="visit" target="_blank" title="Visit QR Source"></a></div>
```

Comment: Hello Brandon, Thank you for you detailed answer but i want to ask where am i supposed to add the code you provided ?

Comment: @Sayaji You'll need to add `qrcode.min.js` first, then your HTML element `#qrcode`, then a `<script>` tag with all the QR Code logic inside (`const qrcode = new QRCode...`)

Comment: @Sayaji please see my updated example. This code, from either example will work in your own codebase. Just add the code as I instructed before.

Comment: Brandon, i have added the code exactly as you instructed, check the edits ,but it's not working and i cant even find where is it going wrong, probably because i have never worked on JS

Comment: @Saysji His code will work as is in any standard environment. There must be another issue with your environment we can’t see from the code you provided. Please let me know if you would like to jump on a screen share where I can troubleshoot this with you

Comment: Yes, I'd really like to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232011/discussion-between-sayaji-and-brandon-mcconnell).

Comment: How do you use this in the webcomponents?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using [davidshimjs/qrcodejs](https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs) ?

When you're doing `new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), url);`, the lib expect `document.getElementById("qrcode")` to return the elem.
In the html code you provided, you don't seems to have that element.

You can try to add `<div id="qrcode"></div>` in your html file to display the output QR code

Comment: Hey, Thank you for you respone, I have updated my code wicth code your provided but it did not work.

Comment: can you tell me what am i missing ?

Comment: The logic seems good to me. Make sure the lib you are using is loaded and working properly first (for example by generating a simple qrcode). If that works, you should try debugging your code to verify your `generateQR` is called and that the parameters are the ones you expect.

Comment: I am working on this for so long now, every link on google has turned purple, I just don't undertand what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

```js
const qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById('qrcode'), {
  text: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/qrcode.min.js',
  width: 128,
  height: 128,
  colorDark : '#000',
  colorLight : '#fff',
  correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/qrcode.min.js"></script>

<div id="qrcode"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answers – you can also render the QR code as an SVG (for cleaner lines on high-density displays) using [`<qr-code>`](https://github.com/bitjson/qr-code). It's a no-framework, no-dependencies, customizable, animate-able, SVG-based QR code web component.

It also lets you customize the colors of the QR code, add an image in the center, and even add custom animations:

[image: animated, stylized QR code]

You can experiment with the demo in your browser here: https://qr.bitjson.com/